# What is the difference between latency and response time?

Tags: performance, latency, throughput, low-latency

I started to read famous Martin Fowler book (Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture)

I have to mention that I am reading the book translated into my native language so it might be a reason of my misunderstanding.

I found their definitions (back translation into English):

**Response time** - amount of time to process some external request
**Latency** - minimal amount of time before getting any response.

For me it is the same. Could you please highlight the difference?

Comment: IMHO, **latency** is the absolute minimal time to get a trivially simple reply, whereas **response time** will always be at least as long but will also include some processing time at the other end.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

One way of looking at this is to say that **transport latency + processing time = response time**.

Transport latency is the time it takes for a request/response to be transmitted to/from the processing component. Then you need to add the time it takes to process the request.

As an example, say that 5 people try to print a single sheet of paper at the same time, and the printer takes 10 seconds to process (print) each sheet.

The person whose print request is processed **first** sees a *latency* of 0 seconds and a *processing* time of 10 seconds - so a *response* time of 10 seconds.

Whereas the person whose print request is processed **last** sees a *latency* of 40 seconds (the 4 people before him) and a *processing* time of 10 seconds - so a *response* time of 50 seconds.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/low-latency/info but here a bit another explanation: *In computing terms, latency describe the time it takes to perform an action. Low latency implies this should be particularly short. It is usually in the range of timings which cannot be seen, only measured.*

Comment: I am absolutely confused

Comment: @gstackoverflow, the terminology is not as important as understanding that the total response time consists of more than just the time it takes to process a request.

Comment: @RoadWarrior I want to be ready if someone ask me to measure latency of my service. What should I measure at this case?

Comment: Let say my service is a Rest service

Comment: @gstackoverflow, ask them how they define latency in the context of your REST service. Do they mean transmission time, processing time, or total response time?

Comment: @RoadWarrior ok, I understood - this definition a bit vagy

Answer (score 31):

*As Martin Kleppman says in his book Designing Data Intensive Applications:*

**Latency** is the duration that a request is waiting to be handled - during which it is latent, awaiting service. Used for diagnostic purposes ex: Latency spikes. High latency can indicate network congestion or long physical distances between the client and server.

**Response time** is the time between a client sending a request and receiving a response. It is the sum of round trip latency, processing delays and queueing delays (normally due to CPU's parallelism limitations). It is used to describe the performance of application.

Comment: "It is the sum of round trip latency and service time. It is used to describe the performance of application."


Is this line actually mentioned in the textbook? I could not find it in Chapter 1. Though, It actually makes it more clear by saying latency is a part of the response time.

Comment: This is not a direct quote from the book. The first version of this question was, until it was edited.

Answer (score 11):

This [article](http://www.javidjamae.com/2005/04/07/response-time-vs-latency/) is a good read on the difference, and is best summarized with this simple equation,

> Latency + Processing Time = Response Time

where

- Latency = the time the message is in transit between two points (e.g. on the network, passing through gateways, etc.)
- Processing time = the time it takes for the message to be processed (e.g. translation between formats, enriched, or whatever)
- Response time = the sum of these.

If processing time is reasonably short, which in well designed systems is the case, then for *practical* purposes response time and latency could be the same in terms of perceived passage of time. That said, to be precise, use the defined terms and don't confuse or conflate the two.

Answer (score 4):

I differentiate this using below example:

A package has been sent from A-B-C where
A-B took 10 sec, B (processing) took 5 sec, B-C took 10 sec

**Latency = (10 + 10) sec = 20 sec**

**Response time = (10 + 5 + 10) sec = 25 sec**

Answer (score 2):

**Latency**
The time from the source sending a packet to the destination receiving it

Latency is the time it takes for a message, or a packet, to travel from its point of origin to the point of destination. That is a simple and useful definition, but it often hides a lot of useful information — every system contains multiple sources, or components, contributing to the overall time it takes for a message to be delivered, and it is important to understand what these components are and what dictates their performance.

Let’s take a closer look at some common contributing components for a typical router on the Internet, which is responsible for relaying a message between the client and the server:

Propagation delay

Amount of time required for a message to travel from the sender to receiver, which is a function of distance over speed with which the signal propagates.

Transmission delay

Amount of time required to push all the packet’s bits into the link, which is a function of the packet’s length and data rate of the link.

Processing delay

Amount of time required to process the packet header, check for bit-level errors, and determine the packet’s destination.

Queuing delay

Amount of time the packet is waiting in the queue until it can be processed.

The total latency between the client and the server is the sum of all the delays just listed
**Response Time**
Total time taken between the packet to send  and receive the packet from the receiver

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *Could you please highlite **the difference**?*

Let me start using a know-how from professionals in ITU-T ( former CCITT ), who have for decades spent many thousands of man*years of efforts on the highest levels of professional experience, and have developed an accurate and responsible methodology for measuring both:

### What have the industry-standards adopted for coping with this ?

Since early years of international industry standards ( well, as far as somewhere deep in 60-ies ), these industry-professionals have created concept of testing complex systems in a repeatable and re-inspectable manner.

```
 System-under-Test (SuT), inter-connected and inter-acting across a mediation service mezzo-system

 SuT-component-[A]
 |
 +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[A]-interface-A.0
 |           +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[A]-interface-A.1
 |           |
 |           |                                                                      SuT-component-[B]
 |           |                                                                      |
 |           |                                                                      +-------------------------[B]-interface-B.1
 |           |                                                                      |               +---------[B]-interface-B.0
 |           |                          ????????????????                            |               |
 |           |                          ? mezzo-system ?                            |               |
 +-----------+                          ????????????????                            +---------------+
 |           | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ??? ...  ... ???  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  |               |
 |           | ~~<channel [A] to ???>~~ ??? ...  ... ???  ~~<channel ??? to [B]>~~  |               |
 |           | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ??? ...  ... ???  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  |               |
 +-----------+                          ????????????????                            +---------------+
 |
```

No matter how formal this methodology may seem, it brings both clarity and exactness, when formulating ( the same when designing, testing and validating ) the requirements closely and explicitly related to SuT-components, SuT-interfaces, SuT-channels and also constraints for interactions across exo-system(s), including limitations of responses to an appearance of any external ( typically adverse ) noise/disturbing events.

At the end, and to the benefit of clarity, all parts of the intended SuT-behaviour could be declared against a set of unambiguously defined and documented **REFERENCE_POINT(s)**, for which the standard defines and documents all properties.

### A Rule of Thumb :

The **LATENCY**, most often expressed as a **TRANSPORT**-LATENCY ( between a pair of **REFERENCE_POINT**s ) is related to a duration of a trivial / primitive event-propagation across some sort of channel(s), where event-processing does not transform the content of the propagated-event. ( Ref. memory-access latency - does not re-process the data, but just delivers it, taking some time to "make it" )

The **PROCESSING** is meant as that kind of transforming an event, in some remarkable manner inside a SuT-component.

The **RESPONSE TIME** ( observed on REFERENCE_POINT(s) of the same SuT-component ) is meant as a resulting duration of some kind of rather complex, End-to-End transaction processing, that is neither a trivial *TRANSPORT LATENCY* across a channel, nor a simplistic in-SuT-component *PROCESSING*, but a some sort of composition of several ( potentially many ) such mutually interacting steps, working along the chain of causality ( adding random stimuli, where needed, for representing noise/errors disturbances ). ( Ref. database-engine response-times creep with growing workloads, right due to increased concurrent use of some processing resources, that are needed for such requested information internal retrieval, internal re-processing and for final delivery re-processing, before delivering resulting "answer" to the requesting counter-party )

```
 |
 |            SuT_[A.0]: REFERENCE_POINT: receives an { external | internal } <sourceEvent>
 |           /
 |          /         _SuT-[A]-<sourceEvent>-processing ( in SuT-[A] ) DURATION
 |         /         /
 |        /         /                          _an known-<channel>-transport-LATENCY from REFERENCE_POINT SuT-[A.1] to <mezzo-system> exosystem ( not a part of SuT, yet a part of the ecosystem, in which the SuT has to operate )
 |       /         /                          /
 |      /         /                          /                  _a mezzo-system-(sum of all)-unknown-{ transport-LATENCY | processing-DURATION } duration(s)
 |     /         /                          /                  /
 |    /         /                          /                  /                         _SuT_[B.1]: REFERENCE_POINT: receives a propagated <sourceEvent>
 |   /         /                          /                  /                         /
 |  /         /                          /                  /                         /                _SuT_[B.0]: REFERENCE_POINT: delivers a result == a re-processed <sourceEvent>
 | /         /                          /                  /                       | /              | /
 |/         /|                         /................  /                        |/               |/
 o<_________>o ~~< chnl from [A.1] >~~? ??? ...  ... ??? ?~~<chnl to [B.1]>~~~~~~? o<______________>o
 |           |\                                                                   \                \
 |           | \                                                                   \                \_SuT-[B]-<propagated<sourceEvent>>-processing ( in SuT-[B] ) DURATION
 |           |  \                                                                   \
 |           |   \_SuT_[A.1]: REFERENCE_POINT: receives                              \_an known-<channel>-transport-LATENCY from <mezzo-system to REFERENCE_POINT SuT_[B.1]
 |           |
 |           |                                                                     |                |
 o<--------->o-----SuT-test( A.0:A.1 )                                             |                |
 |           |                                                                     |                |
 |           |                                                                     o<-------------->o---SuT-test( B.1:B.0 )
 |           |                                                                     |                |
 |           o<----may-test( A.1:B.1 )-------------------------------------------->o                |
 |           |         exo-system that is outside of your domain of control,       |                |
 |                     indirectly, using REFERENCE_POINT(s) that you control                        |
 |                                                                                                  |
 |                                                                                                  |
 o<-----SuT-End-to-End-test( A.0:B.0 )------------------------------------------------------------->o
 |                                                                                                  |
```

Using this ITU-T / CCITT methodology, an example of a well defined **RESPONSE TIME** test would be a test of completing a transaction, that will measure a net duration between delivering a source-event onto REFERENCE_POINT [A.0] ( entering SuT-component-[A] ) and waiting here until the whole SuT delivers an answer from any remote part(s) ( like a delivery from [A]-to-[B], plus a processing inside a SuT-component-[B] and an answer delivery from [B]-back-to-[A] ) until an intended response is received back on a given REFERENCE_POINT ( be it the same one [A.0] or another, purpose-specific one [A.37] ).

Being as explicit as possible saves potential future mis-understanding ( which the international industry standards fought to avoid since ever ).

So a requirement expressed like:

1) a **RESPONSE_TIME( A.0:A.37 ) must be under `125 [ms]`**
2) a net **TRANSPORT LATENCY( A.1:B.1 ) ought exceed `30 [ms]` in less than 0.1% cases per BAU**

are clear and sound ( and easy to measure ) and everybody interested can interpret both the SuT-setup and the test-results.

Meeting these **unambiguous requirements** qualify a such defined SuT-behaviour to safely become compliant with an intended set of behaviours, or let professionals to cheaply detect, document and disqualify those, who do not.